# Setting up PDF outlines from Lua

Tags: luatex, bookmarks

In recent versions of LuaTeX, the PDF outline hierarchy may be set up from the TeX side with `\pdfextension outline`; for example:

```
\pdfextension outline goto page \the\c@page {} count 1 {Chapter 1}
\pdfextension outline attr{/F 1} goto name{label} {Section 1.1}
```

I would like to do this from Lua. Something like:

```
pdf.setoutlines( whatever )
```

… but there isn't such interface.

I have thought about going with raw PDF objects by using `pdf.immediateobj`, but I don't know to do it. If it's possible to accomplish this that way, could you please show an example hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would have to write out raw pdf objects. Here is a minimal example, consisting of two bookmarked pages.

The file `outlines-example.tex` (compile it with plain `luatex`):

```tex
This is the first page.
\vfil\break
This is the second page.
\directlua{require('outline-examples')}
\bye
```

The file `outlines-example.lua`:

```lua
-- Reserve all object numbers beforehand
local first, second, outlines =
  pdf.reserveobj(), pdf.reserveobj(), pdf.reserveobj()

-- Write out the bookmarks
pdf.immediateobj(first, string.format(
  '<< /Title (First page) /Parent %d 0 R /Next %d 0 R /Dest [0 /XYZ] >>',
    outlines, second))
pdf.immediateobj(second, string.format(
  '<< /Title (Second page) /Parent %d 0 R /Prev %d 0 R /Dest [1 /XYZ] >>',
    outlines, first))

-- Write out the outline dictionary
pdf.immediateobj(outlines, string.format(
  '<< /Type/Outlines /First %d 0 R /Last %d 0 R /Count 2 >>',
    first, second))

-- Add the outline dictionary to the document catalog
pdf.setcatalog(string.format(
  '%s /Outlines %d 0 R',
    pdf.getcatalog() or '', outlines))
```